# Activate plugin button do nothing

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I've wrote a Wordpress plugin, it works well offline on my local website, but not when I put it in production ? 
The installation works very well but the activation button is not working...
Is someone know how to fix this issue ?

Thanks for futures answer !

More Information maybe, the plugin uses composer and PhpSpreadReader, I know it need some particular php library, i'm hosted at OVH ! Maybe there is no the library installed on the server ?

```
if (!defined('EXCELREADER_TEMPLATE_URL'))
      define('EXCELREADER_TEMPLATE_URL', dirname(FILE) . "/templates");

if (!defined('EXCELREADER_URL'))
      define('EXCELREADER_URL', plugin_dir_url(FILE));

if (!defined('EXCELREADER_COMPOSER_URL'))
      define('EXCELREADER_COMPOSER_URL', dirname(FILE) . "/vendor");

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

include 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'includes/class-php-spread-reader.php';
require 'includes/widget-excel-reader.php';

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'excelreader');

add_filter('admin_init', 'check_if_we_should_change_upload_dir', 999);

//This goes inside Plugin A.
//When A is activated. activate B.
register_activation_hook(FILE, 'excelreader_activate');
function excelreader_activate()
{
      $dependent = 'excelreader.php';
      if (is_plugin_inactive($dependent)) {
            add_action('update_option_active_plugins', 'my_activate_dependent_excelreader');
      }
}

function my_activate_dependent_excelreader()
{
      $dependent = 'excelreader.php';
      activate_plugin($dependent);
}

// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget()
{
      register_widget('excelreader_widget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget');

class ExcelReader
{
      /**
*
*   Chemin du dossier où sont sauvegarder les xlsx déja entrée
*
*/
      private $dirfxlxs;

  /**


*
*   Instance de la classe PhpSpreadReader
*
*/
      private $phpspread;

  protected static $instance;

  public static function get_instance()
  {
        if (!self::$instance) {
              self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
  }


  /**


*
*   Constructeur
*
*/
      public function construct()
      {
            // Admin page calls:
            sql_install();
            add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'addAdminMenu'));
            add_action('wp_ajax_store_admin_data', array(&$this, 'storeAdminData'));
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'addAdminScripts'));
            register_activation_hook(__FILE, array(&$this, 'plugin_activate'));
            //add_action( 'init', array($this,'load_translation') );
      }

  public function plugin_activate()
  {
        if (version_compare(get_bloginfo('version'), '1.0', ' < ')) {
              deactivate_plugins(basename(__FILE__));
        } else {
              $rlm_rsvplus_options = array(
                    'db_version'          => '1.0',
                    'event_name'          => '',
                    'end_date'            => '',
              );

              update_option('rlm_myplugin_options', $rlm_myplugin_options);
        }
  }

  /**


*
*   Display the Plugin on admin menu panel
* @return void
*
**/
      public function addAdminMenu()
      {
            add_menu_page(
                  __('ExcelReader', 'excelreader'),
                  __('ExcelReader', 'excelreader'),
                  'manage_options',
                  'excelreader',
                  array($this, 'adminLayout'),
                  ''
            );
      }

  /**


*  Outputs the Admin Dashboard layout containing the form with all its options
 *  Display on Admin Page
* @return void
*/

  public function adminLayout()
  {
        $this->display_enter_a_file();
        /*if(isset($this->phpspread))
           $this->phpspread->display_excelfile();*/
        //  $this->display_wc_categories();
  }

  /**


*
 *  Affichage du formulaire pour le fichier
*   @return void
**/

  public function display_enter_a_file()
  {


// SOME CODE HERE NOT IMPORTANT CAUSE ALL IS WORKING AT THIS LVL
}

/**
 *
 *  Date pour le fichier XLS Sauvegarde
*   @return string
**/

public function getDateAndTime()
{
      $now = new DateTime();
      return $now->getTimestamp();
}

/**
 *
 *  Sauvergarde du fichier dans wp-content/uploads
*   @return true
**/

public function upload_user_file(array $file)
{
      // Check that the nonce is valid, and the user can edit this post.
      if (
            isset($_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], $_POST['post_id'])
            && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload')
      ) {
            // Let WordPress handle the upload.
            // Remember, 'my_image_upload' is the name of our file input in our form above.
            $this->clean_folder();
            $attachment_id = media_handle_upload('my_image_upload', $_POST['post_id']);

        if (is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
              // There was an error uploading the image.
              echo "Une erreur est survenu a l'upload"; ?><br><?php

  } else {
        echo "Fichier Upload"; ?><br><?php
                    $this->phpspread = new PhpSpreadReader();
                    $this->phpspread->read_file_php_spread();
              }
        } else {
              echo "Probleme durant l'upload ";
              ?><br><?php


// The security check failed, maybe show the user an error.
      }
}

/**
*
*   Nettoyer le répertoire du dossier wordpress
*   @return void
**/
                  public function clean_folder()
                  {
                        $files = glob(wp_upload_dir()['path'] . "/*"); // get all file names
                        foreach ($files as $file) { // iterate files
                              if (is_file($file))
                                    unlink($file); // delete file
                        }
                  }

/**
 *
 * Appel des fonctions dans le panel admin
 * @return void
 **/
                  public function addAdminScripts()
                  { }
            }

        ExcelReader::get_instance();
```

Comment: At the moment it does not appear you have the plugin activation code.

Comment: Thx for your answer MaxYudin  have you a documentation for get this code ?

Comment: Time delay happened between my comment and your code publications. Now there is the code to scrutinize.

Comment: I've found the documentation and the register code was here,  sorry for my bad copy/pasta !

Comment: I've always the proplem, if i've found a solution i put it... Please if someone can help i will be very gratefull...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright the problem was from my hosting and more of that my stupidity, wrong version of php used in production...

Comment: There's no stupid questions my friend. Learn from your errors and be happy, that is what it is, that's life.